# Criptografia em hash C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, criptografia

Consegui criar um cadastro com senha criptografada, porém no método de acessar(fazer login) estou com dúvida em como pegar a senha digitada e comparar com a senha cadastrada com criptografia. Segue meu código:

```
class FuncionarioDAO
    {
        public bool tem = false;
        public String mensagem = "";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        Conexao conexaoBD = new Conexao();
        SqlDataReader dr;

        public bool acessar(String usuario, String senha)
        {
            var hash = new Hash(SHA512.Create());
            string hashTxtSenha = null;            

            cmd.CommandText = "select * from funcionario where FuncionarioLogin = @usuario and Senha = @senha";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", usuario);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@senha", senha);           

            try
            {
                cmd.Connection = conexaoBD.Conectar();
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               hashTxtSenha = hash.CriptografarSenha(senha);
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    if(hash.VerificarSenha(hashTxtSenha, senha))
                    {
                        tem = true;
                    }                                                          
                }
                conexaoBD.Desconectar();
                dr.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {

                this.mensagem = "Erro com Banco de Dados!";
            }
            return tem;
        }

        public String cadastrar(String usuario, String senha, String confirmar, String nome, String email, String telefone, String celular, String nivelAcesso, String nomeExibicao)
        {
            var hash = new Hash(SHA512.Create());
            tem = false;
            if(senha.Equals(confirmar))
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"insert into Funcionario  
                                (FuncionarioLogin, Senha, Nome, Email, Telefone, Celular, NivelAcesso, NomeExibicao)
                               values (@usuario, @senha, @nome, @email, @telefone, @celular, @nivelAcesso, @nomeExibicao)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", usuario);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@senha", hash.CriptografarSenha(senha));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", nome);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefone", telefone);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@celular", celular);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nivelAcesso", nivelAcesso);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeExibicao", nomeExibicao);                

                try
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conexaoBD.Conectar();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conexaoBD.Desconectar();
                    this.mensagem = "Cadastrado com Sucesso!";
                    tem = true;

                }
                catch (SqlException)
                {

                    this.mensagem = "Erro com Banco de Dados!";
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                this.mensagem = "Senhas não correspondem!";
            }
            return mensagem;
        }
}
```

---

Minha classe hash está assim:

```
public class Hash
{
    private HashAlgorithm _algoritmo;

    public Hash(HashAlgorithm algoritmo)
    {
        _algoritmo = algoritmo;
    }

    public string CriptografarSenha(string senha)
    {
        var valorCodificado = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(senha);
        var senhaCifrada = _algoritmo.ComputeHash(valorCodificado);
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var caractere in senhaCifrada)
        {
            sb.Append(caractere.ToString("X2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    public bool VerificarSenha(string senhaDigitada, string senhaCadastrada)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(senhaCadastrada))
            throw new NullReferenceException("Cadastre uma senha.");
        var senhaCifrada = _algoritmo.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(senhaDigitada));
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var caractere in senhaCifrada)
        {
            sb.Append(caractere.ToString("X2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString() == senhaCadastrada;
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque sua classe Hash pra vermos o que ela está comparando

Comment: Não basta você pegar o que o usuário digitou, criptografar e verificar se o o retorno de um select para essa senha retorna true ou false do banco?

Comment: Minha dúvida é exatamente como faço para comparar o que foi digitado com o que está cadastrado

Answer (score 0):

Como você esta criptografando a senha antes de de inserir no banco, você vai precisar criptografa da mesma forma para usar no parâmetro do seu select caso contrario você não vai acha seu dado no banco.

Veja como ficaria.

```
public bool acessar(String usuario, String senha)
{
    bool tem = false;
    var hash = new Hash(SHA512.Create());
    string hashTxtSenha = = hash.CriptografarSenha(senha);            

    cmd.CommandText = "select * from funcionario where FuncionarioLogin = @usuario and Senha = @senha";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", usuario);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@senha", hashTxtSenha);           

    try
    {
        cmd.Connection = conexaoBD.Conectar();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();      

        tem = dr.HasRows;
        BD.Desconectar();

        dr.Close();
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        this.mensagem = "Erro com Banco de Dados!";
    }
    return tem;
}
```